# One large Stream, or several smaller Streams?

Tags: .net

I am using `XmlTextWriter` to create a large (huge) xml string but I wonder if I should create more than one writer and create smaller xml instead of just a big one.  In regards to memory and performance what is the impact by having huge xml streams versus smaller streams?

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter myXml = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create smaller xml instead of big one. When you have huge xml streams parsing through the streams or using that object to save the xml can be slower as compared to the smaller streams.

Comment: If you think my answer has helped you or if you think this is the solution please accept the answer or vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Many small xml is almost always better than a single big xml.

As far as Framework 4.0, StringWriter & XmlTextWriter are single threaded. By splitting the huge xml to smaller xmls you can dramatically improve performance by assigning each xml task to a different thread.

Comment: Whaoo... Thank you for the info Gilad.